# How to remove controls when drag, drop and delete objects on FabricJS canvas

Tags: fabricjs

**Sorry. I wasn't sure enough. Found the answer.**
http://fabricjs.com/docs/fabric.Canvas.html#discardActiveObject

---

I was able to delete the selected object by dragging and dropping it with reference to the answer below, but the control remains after deleting.

### Reference answer

[javascript - Drag, drop and delete objects on FabricJS canvas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42850899/drag-drop-and-delete-objects-on-fabricjs-canvas#answer-42860441)

### Forked page

https://jsfiddle.net/926Lvw3x/

```
canvas.on('mouse:up', function(evn) {
    var x = evn.e.offsetX;
    var y = evn.e.offsetY;
    if (x > bin.left && x < (bin.left + bin.width) &&
        y > bin.top && y < (bin.top + bin.height)) {
        canvas.remove(...canvas.getActiveObjects());
        canvas.discardActiveObject(); // Adding this line removes the control
    }
});
```

I would like to know how to remove the control when the selected object is removed.